# Keep getting No-Matching-Unique errors when I references exist primary key columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm practicing some SQL and I'm confused.

I learned `constraint constName primary key(a, b)` to set 2 columns as the primary key, and I did it what my professor said, but I can't reference this primary key.

How can I set 2 PK columns in `Seat` table and reference these columns from `Revervation_Details` table without errors?

Here's my code:

```
create table Schedule
(
    Schedule_SN number(10) primary key,
    Theater_SN REFERENCES Theater(Theater_SN) not null,
    Movie_SN REFERENCES Movie(Movie_SN) not null,
    ScreeningDate date not null,
    StartTime timestamp not null,
    Price number(6) not null
);

create table Seat
(
    Schedule_SN REFERENCES Schedule(Schedule_SN) not null,
    Seat_SN varchar2(10) not null,

    constraint Seat_PK primary key(Schedule_SN, Seat_SN)
);

create table Reservation
(
    Reservation_SN number(15) primary key,
    ID REFERENCES Member(ID) not null,
    DCtype number(2) not null,
    DCamount number(7),
    PaymentMethod number(1) not null,
    TotalPrice number(7) not null,
    ReservationDate date not null
);

create table Reservation_Details
(
    Reservation_SN REFERENCES Reservation(Reservation_SN) not null,
    Schedule_SN REFERENCES Schedule(Schedule_SN) not null,
    Seat_SN REFERENCES Seat(Seat_SN) not null,

    constraint Reservation_DetailsPK primary key(Reservation_SN, Schedule_SN)
);
```

This is the error I get:

> ORA-02270: no matching unique or primary key for this column-list
> 02270. 00000 -  "no matching unique or primary key for this column-list"
> *Cause:    A REFERENCES clause in a CREATE/ALTER TABLE statement gives a column-list for which there is no matching unique or primary key constraint in the referenced table.
> *Action:   Find the correct column names using the ALL_CONS_COLUMNS catalog view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this foreign key:

```
Seat_SN REFERENCES Seat(Seat_SN) not null
```

Seat_SN columns needs to a primary key or a unique key in:

```
create table Seat(
Schedule_SN REFERENCES Schedule(Schedule_SN) not null,
Seat_SN varchar2(10) not null,
constraint Seat_PK primary key(Schedule_SN, Seat_SN)
);
```

You cannot have 2 primary keys in one table but you can have one primary key and many unique keys:

```
 create table Seat(
    Schedule_SN REFERENCES Schedule(Schedule_SN) not null,
    Seat_SN varchar2(10) not null unique,
    constraint Seat_PK primary key(Schedule_SN, Seat_SN)
    );
```